# UITableview image problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get images to work in UITableView - can you if possible have a look at the code as see why I cannot retrieve the array LogoURL in cellForRowAtINdexPath, and also is this the right way of doing this ?    Thanks very much everyone. Jason.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"
                                                applicationKey:@""];
        self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
        self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
        query.fetchLimit = 3;
        [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
         {
             //add the items to our local cop
             self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
            [self.TableView reloadData];
         }];
    }


    - (void)SQLRetrieve:(NSString *)barID

    {
        //NSLog(@"%@", barID);

        NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": barID};
        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
        [self.client invokeAPI:@"photos"
                          body:barIDDictionary
                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                    parameters:nil
                       headers:nil
                    completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                        } else
                        {
                            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                            NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                            NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                            NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                            NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                            NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];


                            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [self doSomethingWithReturnString:finalstring];
                            });
                        }
                    }];
    }


    -(void)doSomethingWithReturnString:(NSString*)string
    {
        self.LogoURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.LogoURL addObject:string];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.LogoURL);


    }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [self.rowitems count];
        NSLog(@"%d",[self.rowitems count]);

    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
            NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = apt[@"content"];
            [self SQLRetrieve:apt[@"barID"]];
            return cell;

    }
```

Comment: What library does MSQuery come from?

Comment: Are you getting a error?

Comment: No nothing no. I just cannot see the array in cellforIndexPath and so therefore I cannot get the URL's which are in there. The URL's are pointers to the images.

Comment: I think it is the program flow. As I can see the urls above in the doSomethingWithString method. but this really does not help me. Is it to do with the [reloaddata] statement in the completion block ??

Comment: FYI doSomethingWithReturnString creates a new NSMutableArray each time meaning anything already in it is wiped

Comment: you mean the alloc init command ?

Comment: yes if this method is called multiple times it will overwrite any previous data in the array.

Comment: I have removed that now and I am still getting blank arrays - but this time I am getting the brackets (  ), and this is when I put an NSLOG in cellforindexpath. so they are still not transferring over.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way. Made my own Class of cell (notecell).

the method who defines the view of the cell in class note cell is the init of itself:

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        _dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
        _noteLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 200, 50)];
        [self addSubview:_noteLabel];
        [self addSubview:_dateLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

        - (void)setDateLabelValue:(NSString *)dateValueString
    {
        _dateLabel.text = dateValueString;
    }

    - (void)setNoteLabelValue:(NSString *)noteValueString
    {
        _noteLabel.text = noteValueString;
    }
```

And here I am using that in the tableview

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NoteCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NoteCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *oneDict = [_noteBookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setDateLabelValue:[oneDict objectForKey:@"timestamp"]];
    [cell setNoteLabelValue:[oneDict objectForKey:@"value"]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

does that help you?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ?? Did you get them by putting an _underscore under the array name ?

Comment: I overwrote cell with notecell as own class , so that I am able to  extend cell with my own methods .This own methods set the view in notecell like I want it. and here I am only calling these methods. the _underscore is nothing else as self.notebookarray. the array which is stored in this tableviewcontroller. Means its a class Value i you want so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the array is nil is because you `[self.client invokeAPI..]` Method uses a call back -- Ill think you will find that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method completes before your completion handler is finished. This is essentially a race condition.

To test this place a breakpoint in `rowForIndexPath` and one in the completion handler. Ill think you will find that `rowForIndexPath` finishes executing before the completion block does.

Your array will be nil until the completion block calls `doSomethingWithReturnString` which I believe will happen after.

I suggest you move `[table reloadData]` into the compleation handler in `SQLRetriveCode`  so that `cellForRowAtrIndexPath` is only called once the array has been populated. You then also need  to move the `SQLRetriveCode` out of the `cellForRowAtrIndexPath` or else it will never be called. Ill leave it to you where you want to put this, maybe in the completion block in the `viewDidLoad`(if only just to test this fixes it)

Comment: makes sense, so what shall i do ?

Comment: ok I have moved [table reloadData] to the completion block for SQLRetireve after the [self doSomethingWithReturnString:finalstring]; I am not sure I understand move the SQLRETRIEVECODE from CellForRowAtIndexPath[self SQLRetrieve:apt[@"barID"]]; cos that runs it with the barID, as you can see from the code. Your very good at this GeminiCoder.

Comment: I admit It will need some work. But you need to call the SQLRetrive prior to cellForRowArtIndexPath. cellForRowArtIndexPath can only be called once the data has been pulled. I suggest you move it and put some hard coded data in it to test what I’m saying works. If it does then you will have to move the code out of the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Sorry but with mutithreded code the order is really important.

Comment: ok mate, so [table reloadData] will re-run cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: yes that’s right in fact it will call all the methods in the UITableViewDataSource protocol https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Any table view image loading problem comes down to following steps:

1. Load data into data source - from REST / database
2. Create and initialize relevant data model objects
3. `[tableView reloaddata]`
4. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, include code that will set image from correct data model object. This step might be little quirky because of cell reuse done by table view.

To avoid problems, refer to [this tutorial about lazy loading](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-app-design-blog-load-images-asynchronously-inside-uitableview/) of images inside table view.